# Generating negative voltage rail using P7805 DC-DC converter

Tags: power-supply, analog, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, negative-voltage

I need to create a negative voltage rail (from positive supply rail), say -5V to keep a P-MOS transistor in ON-state even when the voltage on its [S] source is 0V. So I found this schematic in [an answer of another question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/353279/101852), but does this actually work?

[image]

Comment: C1 needs to be between pins 1 and 3 instead (I'm assuming you're using CUI's P7805).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief this does work, but the P7805 is a DC to DC converter and it can sink current. A regular 7805 voltage regulator requires a negative supply, this does not. Here is a excerpt from the P7805 datasheet:

[image]
Source: https://www.cui.com/product/resource/p7805-s.pdf

Comment: Uhhhh, let marketing decide the name of a component is harmful… +1 for pointing this out!

Comment: Well, they wanted it to be drop in comparable with a 7805... I agree bad idea

Comment: Wow, this is entirely different thing than one may think of...bad naming 100%. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone else not spotting it immediately: the 2 and 3 pins stealthily switch places.

Comment: Also, note that in this circuit C1 is between pin 1 and 3 of the converter, while in OP's version it's between pins 1 and 2.

Comment: The OP's schematic has the input capacitor C1 between pins 1 and 2, as opposed to between pins 1 and 3 as it's supposed to be.