# Are there commercial split +/-5V DC power supplies?

Tags: power-supply, split-supply

I have a custom amplifier board that works with some scientific equipment.  There is a molex-type connector on the PCB that requires +5V, -5V, and ground (3 pins). When I try to search for a +/- split power supply, I can find lots of do-it-yourself instructions for how to create the split supply, but no ready-made commercial product that I can just plug in. (Not expecting my specific connector, but screw terminals or banana jacks or something...

Are there commercial products to supply split +/-5V and I'm just using the wrong search terms? If not, is there some reason, given how common this need is for analog components?

Comment: Yes, just search for a dual output AC/DC converter or DC/DC converter with +5V and -5V outputs.

Comment: Yes, dual laboratory power supplies and others exist. You however tell very little about what properties you need, like current or ripple.

Comment: Old school method used by HP was make +/-7V supply then used dual LDO’s on each load. Or send 5/-5V ref and a buffer on each regulated with unity gain.

Comment: @Justme I'm using a benchtop lab power supply now, but it seems like overkill. I eventually need at least 5 of these, and getting a benchtop supply for each one can't be the optimal solution

Comment: What power level / output current?

Comment: Digikey shows 71 models of +/- 5v dual rail power supply in stock.  A solution I prefer when designing my own (lower power) boards is to put a charge pump voltage inverter to convert +5 into -5v and then run everything off of 5v.  You can also use a 5.25v supply and LDOs if you require low noise.

Comment: This is a low power application. The board is totally custom and didn't come with a current spec, but it's only powering a few source-followers

Comment: @user1850479 these are not boards we're designing; they already exist and we just need to run them.  I have no idea why the designers decided to take split supply input rather than splitting it on the board, but that's what we're working with

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I could certainly have our in-house electronics guys whip something up, but it will cost 100X more than buying a commercial supply. I just could not find the right keywords to search with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many many ±5V supplies. Look on Digikey or Mouser under DC DC converters, choose your search terms to be two output, look for packages that are SIP. If you're looking for a bench top supply and dual benchtop supply will probably work for your application.

This is a good way I've used in the past to obtain -5V, the same converter (in a different configuration ) can generate +5V.

[Generating negative voltage rail using P7805 DC-DC converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454778/generating-negative-voltage-rail-using-p7805-dc-dc-converter/454786#454786)

Comment: was hoping for AC input, but the DC-DC converters seem like the best solution.  I'm using a dual-output benchtop now but it's overkill (and I need 5 of them)

Comment: The most common way with AC to DC 'wall warts' is to use a single supply, then use a DC DC converter to make two rails.

Comment: Simplest way from mains is to get a split secondary transformer (like a 10-0-10 output) and regulate the output (trivially with 7805 and 7905). Depend on how much current you need. Or just take a +5 supply and apply an inverting converter.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio This is a good inverting -5V converter, the same converter can be used for +5V and they are in 7805 compatible packages. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454778/generating-negative-voltage-rail-using-p7805-dc-dc-converter/454786#454786